# Anchor UILabel to the Right when resizing inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I have a label inside my UITableViewCell. I have set it up in Interface Builder with it's maximum width. After I have set the text on the label I am resizing it using "SizeToFit".

The problem I am having is that when I resize the label it resizes fixed to the left of it's original position.

I want to resize it to the right of it's original position so that it is anchored to the right.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set its `autoresizingMask` property to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`.